# Xcode tests fail due to missing library in test bundle

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

Using Xcode 7.3, Cocoapods 0.39.0

At some point in the recent past, perhaps due to an upgrade of Xcode and/or Cocoapods, our tests stopped working with the following runtime issue:

```
2016-04-18 16:32:55.318 MyApp[15066:9003314] Failed to load test bundle
from file:///<huge filepath to .xctest wrapper>: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain
Code=3587 "dlopen_preflight(<same huge filepath to .xctest wrapper>): Library not
loaded: @rpath/Nocilla.framework/Nocilla

Reason: image not found" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle is damaged
or missing necessary resources., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the
bundle., NSFilePath=<huge filepath to .xctest wrapper>, NSDebugDescription=
dlopen_preflight(<huge filepath to .xctest wrapper>): Library not loaded:
@rpath/Nocilla.framework/Nocilla
```

I don't know anything like enough about Xcode and test bundle internals to debug this.

How do I restore my tests to working order? Thank you.

Edit: The only way I was able to unblock my work was to remove Nocilla. Fortunately, I discovered it wasn't actually used for anything. We just as well could have relied on it, however, so the question stands.

Comment: in my case even removing framework doesn't help